# How to setup plaidml?

Tags: pycharm, gpu, plaidml

I am using pycharm where I have created an environment using miniconda. I have installed Tensorflow and Keras. Now I wanted to use plaidml to access my GPU (it is Intel 620) so I typed the following command into the terminal of my pycharm terminal:

```
pip install -U plaidml-keras
```

But when I tried to run a program using plaidml backend, it shows:

```
raise plaidml.exceptions.PlaidMLError('PlaidML is not configured. Run plaidml-setup.')
plaidml.exceptions.PlaidMLError: PlaidML is not configured. Run plaidml-setup.
```

So I searched in Internet and found that I have setup it first using `plaidml-setup`. But inserting this command in the pycharm terminal shows:

```
'plaidml-setup' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I know, being a beginner, somewhere I am making horrible mistake but I could not find enough documentation in the internet how to set up plaidml to use in Pycharm. Is there anyone who can just show me where I can find good resource for it?

N.B. In the pycharm project interpreter, it is showing that `plaidml` and `plaidml-keras` both are present (version 0.7.0).

Answer (score 0):

If you use your Pycharm's terminal you should first activate the virtual environment of your project. You can check in your Pycharm project settings where your environment lies and then you have to run (with proper location inserted)

```
source my-venv-location/bin/activate
```

After that you should be able to call

```
plaidml-setup
```